# Webscraping Google news page: getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web-scrape the Google News page for a personal project and retrieve the article headlines to print out onto another page. I've been searching for any typos or mistakes but I'm not sure why my element keeps returning as "None" when I try to print it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=beyond+meat&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS898US898&sxsrf=ALeKk00IH9jp1Kz5-LSyi7FUB4rd6--_hw:1624935518812&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicqIbD7LvxAhVWo54KHXgRA9oQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=754'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('div', id='rso') #grabs everything in column
article_results = results.find_all('div', class_='yr3B8d KWQBje') #grabs divs surrounding each article
for article_result in article_results:
    headliner = article_result.find('div', class_='JheGif nDgy9d')#grabs article header div for every article
    if None in (headliner):
        continue
    headliner_text = headliner.text.strip()
    print()
```

Comment: the url return Forbidden, thus the result is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=beyond+meat&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS898US898&sxsrf=ALeKk00IH9jp1Kz5-LSyi7FUB4rd6--_hw:1624935518812&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicqIbD7LvxAhVWo54KHXgRA9oQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=754'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
headers = soup.find_all('div', class_='BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd')
for h in headers:
    print(h.text)
```

Refer the output... Is this what you are expecting?
[image]

Comment: yes, perfect. I believe I was including too many labels as I thought I had to include the outer container div in order to parse the information within. This is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @melandalin thanks for the confirmation. I am happy as it met your expectation. :)